# How to insert <div> </div> between many divs using jQuery (wordpress)?

Tags: jquery, insert, row

I need make class 3 and 4 in one line.
I have following existing code, and I tried to add  between two divs using append,
but it didn't inset div between divs.
Would you please let me know how to make class 3 and 4 in one line?

Existing code that creted using plugin (class 3 and 4 displays in two lines):

```
<form class="acfef-form">
     <div class="1"></div>
     <div class="2"></div>
     <div class="3">
          <div class="3-1"><input class="acfef-submit-button" type="submit"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="4"><input class="save-progress-button" name="save_progress" type="submit"></div>
</form>
```

[image]

I want to make like this:

```
<form class="acfef-form">
     <div class="1"></div>
     <div class="2"></div>
     <div>
           <div class="3">
                <div class="3-1"><input class="acfef-submit-button" type="submit"></div>
           </div>
           <div class="4"><input class="save-progress-button" name="save_progress" type="submit"></div>
     </div>
</form>
```

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Your description of one line vs two is confusing. Wrapping another div around them doesn't change the number of lines they will display since they are block elements. So is class 3-1 confusing which is an extra line. Is it supposed to be inside class 3?

Comment: Hi charlietfl : thank you for your comment and sorry for my confusing explanation. I added images and upated html code. Would you plaese help me?

Comment: Still not clear what happens to 3-1. Also you want order reversed for 3&4?

Comment: Hi  charlietfl: I'm sorry, I added more attribute in 3-1, yeah, I want to reverse them.

Comment: Still confused. Image doesn't depict where 3-1 ends up. Is it inside #3 and html is incorrect?

Comment: Hi  charlietfl : Yeah, 3-1 is inside class 3. The button shows like images (in two lines)

Comment: `jQuery('.3,.4').wrapAll('<div class="someClass">')`. Then you can apply some flex and order reverse in css

Comment: Hi charlietfl : Oh, wow, thank you for your supportive hlep. I've just found that why you are saying 3 and 3-1 are stange. I edited div. And.. I also tried your code, it works but I can see strange things. Class 3 is Submit button, class 4 is Save Progress button. It shows two more Edit buttons inside the new div after adding the jQuery (suddently appeared). So, now there are 4 buttons. Would you please let me know how to solve this issue? Thaks again  charlietfl : )

Comment: So those classes are not unique and there are more of them somewhere else? If so are they in the same form? This would be a lot easier to deal with having a [mre]

Comment: Yeah, in the same form and added these 2 buttons : https://i.imgur.com/OVJJvrY.jpg (Yep, thank you for your advice, I will learn how to ask questions)

Comment: Could try `jQuery('.3:last,.4:last')`. Still confused and would be so much easier with relevant html

Comment: I tried it, now it shows 3 buttoms like this (https://i.imgur.com/XcbKB4h.jpg). I created the html code here https://jsfiddle.net/webstudioq/L38zgrt2/6/ (I'm not sure if it's helpful). Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by *charlietfl* you can use `wrapAll` to achieve this .Also, other way will be using `prev().addBack().wrapAll()` this will take previous element from your save-progress and then wrap them in one div.

**Demo Code** :

```js
//$("form.acfef-form .acf-form-submit , .save-progress-buttons").wrapAll("<div class='abc'></div>")
//or 
$("form.acfef-form .save-progress-buttons:last").prev().addBack().wrapAll("<div class='abc' />");
```

```css
.abc {
  display: flex;
}

.abc>div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="acfef-form -submit" action="" method="post" autocomplete="disableacf" novalidate="novalidate" data-widget="fc7226d" id="acf-form-fc7226d12597" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="acf-form-data acf-hidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="_acf_screen" value="acfef_form"><input type="hidden" name="_acf_post_id" value="12597"><input type="hidden" name="_acf_nonce" value="fb285841f9"><input type="hidden" name="_acf_validation" value="1"><input type="hidden"
      name="_acf_changed" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="_acf_status" value=""><input type="hidden" name="_acf_form" value="QzNx"><input type="hidden" name="_acf_main_action" value="edit_post"><input type="hidden" name="_acf_screen_id" value="3358">
    <input type="hidden" name="_acf_element_id" value="fc7226d"> </div>
  <div class="acf-fields acf-form-fields -top">
    <div class="acf-field acf-field-product-title acf-field-6053b2640eef9 elementor-repeater-item-b95d154" data-name="title" data-type="product_title" data-key="field_6053b2640eef9">
      <div class="acf-label">
      </div>

      <div class="acf-field acf-field-textarea acf-field-60bc51af899c4 elementor-repeater-item-b95d154" data-name="extra-request" data-type="textarea" data-key="field_60bc51af899c4">
        <div class="acf-label">
          <label for="acf-field_60bc51af899c4">ETC</label></div>
        <div class="acf-input">
          <textarea id="acf-field_60bc51af899c4" name="acf[field_60bc51af899c4]" rows="8"></textarea></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="acf-form-submit">
    <div class="acfef-submit-buttons"><input type="submit" class="acfef-submit-button acf-button button button-primary" data-state="publish" value="Submit"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="save-progress-buttons">
    <input formnovalidate="" type="submit" class="save-progress-button acf-submit-button acf-button button" value="Save Draft" name="save_progress" data-state="revision"></div>

</form>
```

Comment: Hi Swati: Thank you for your help all the time. I tried your code, and it works but shows 2 more buttons after adding the jQuery. So, now there are 4 buttons (https://i.imgur.com/Mbt9zYt.jpg). Would you please let me know how to solve this problem?

Comment: structure which i am using is your original html structure or not ? can you show full html code ? because above snippet work perfectly .

Comment: Also this `$("form.acfef-form .save-progress-buttons:last").prev().addBack()..` also giving same result ?

Comment: Hi Swati: Ooops, sorry, your code works perfectly. Wow, I learnt a new thing again from you. I used this code of yours: jQuery("form.acfef-form .save-progress-buttons").prev().addBack().wrapAll("<div class='abcd' />");. Thank you again Swati : )